# Laravel LIMIT relation using Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a bunch of `Shop`s and `Item`s . Each shop can have a number of different items. However, I want to get all the shops, with only 4 items each.

The following gives me all shops, with all their items:

```
$shops = Shop::with('items')->get();
```

The following gives me all shops, but only with **4 items in total**, and not each.

```
$shops = Shop::with(array('items' => function($query) {
    $query->take(4);
}))->get();
```

How do I get all the shops, with 4 items each?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to get all the shops that have exactly four items?

Comment: I want to get all shops, with a maximum of 4 items per shop

Comment: You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26544839/how-to-limit-records-from-related-table-with-eager-loading and comment on question

Comment: That question ultimately leads to this page which seems to have your answer, though it's a bit confusing and only for MySQL.  http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/

Answer (score 0):

It's due to an SQL limitation.
When eager loading something laravel generate a SQL query that look like

```
SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE id IN (1, 2...) LIMIT 4;
```

So the SQL engine return only 4 row at all.

I can't find a quick workaround do to that in laravel. Even in raw SQL it's a problem hard to solve.

Some reading on this subject [How to select the first/least/max row per group in sql](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/).

Answer (score 0):

```
Shop::with(array('items' => function($query) {
    $query->limit(4);
}))->get();
```

Replacing take with limit should solve your problem.